# AWS EC2 pem key in txt

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, rsa, pem

I am trying to launch aws ec2 server. I got a key pair, but my key looks like privatekey.pem.txt.

If I open it with text editor it looks like normal key, but how could I generate .pem file from it?

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAh89 ...
```

Comment: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAh89 ...

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried simply renaming the file with a .pem extension? i.e. get rid of the .txt? My .pem file is also a text file (though not named as such) and it works just fine.

Comment: Yes , and I got this :
Permissions 0644 for 'Name.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "Name.pem": bad permissions
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: You need to set the permissions to your pem file as per the aws specs:  chmod 400 /path/my-key-pair.pem

Answer (score 1):

You can either use AWS generated PEM key or custom PEM key you have on your computer.

When you generate your key from AWS console or CLI, you just get a PEM file which is your private key and you can use this key in your ssh command line for example. If this key is renamed by either you or your OS(add a .txt), you can just get rid of it and rename it to <key>.pem

When you generate your key by yourself(in RSA format), you have to transform your public key to PEM format before uploading it to AWS. You can do it using the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -f rsa.pub -e -m pem
```

Of course, wherever your key was generated from, you have to change permission:

```
chmod 400 <key>.pem
```

Comment: AWS generated the mykey.pem.txt and I dont know how to turn it in .pem key

Comment: You probably(you or your OS) did this mistake. Just rename the file.